# Facebook share and Tweet

Tags: facebook, api, windows-phone-7, twitter, xna

I want to  put Facebook share and tweet option in my xna based wp7 game. I am not at all sure where to start. Which FB/Twitter API, or any third party? I tried on the net and could not find steps. It would be great to have a link/page which provide me all the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These could be an option..

- [ShareLinkTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharelinktask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
- [ShareStatusTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharestatustask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)